# SQLite, making a query based on Dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've been searching on how to do this but am not coming up with a clear answer (maybe my resources are not that good). I need to make a SQLite query to retrieve data between two dates from a SQLite DB.

I am trying this:

```
SELECT CONTACTNAME
FROM SHIPMENT 
WHERE DATECREATED 
BETWEEN date('11-15-2010') 
AND date('12-25-2010');
```

The data is in my SQLite DB as:

```
CONTACTNAME=VARCHAR
DATECREATED=date (format: "11/22/2010")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just removing date():

```
SELECT CONTACTNAME
FROM SHIPMENT 
WHERE DATECREATED 
BETWEEN '2010-11-15' 
AND '2010-12-25'
```

Comment: ah ok thanks, not sure why the tutorial I read had that in there

Comment: @dan04, can you clarify "that"?  I tried the code I used above on my own SQLite DB, with MM-DD-YYYY order, so am wondering if you are referring to date() or if there are differences in versions of SQLite that might be relevant to others reading this question :)

Comment: it works correctly only at yyyy-MM-dd format. Just see dan04's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, how embarrassing . . .  unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to delete my post because it was accepted :-(  Any more experiences SO users know how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 16):

SQLite does not have a date type.  You can get by with storing dates as strings, but you need to use YYYY-MM-DD date order, **NOT** MM-DD-YYYY.  There are two major reasons for this:

(1) Correct ordering

With YYYY-MM-DD dates, the lexicographical order is the same as the chronological order, which makes the `<`, `>`, and `BETWEEN` operators work as expected.

This is **not** the case for MM-DD-YYYY dates.  A query for dates `BETWEEN '11-15-2010' AND '12-25-2010'` will falsely match `'11-22-1963'` and `'12-21-2012'`.

(2) Compatibility with [SQLite date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

They accept both string and numeric (Julian) dates, but if you pass a string to any of these functions, it has to have YYYY-MM-DD order.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT field_1,field_2,date_field
 WHERE julianday(date_field)
 BETWEEN julianday('1998-01-01') and julianday('2008-01-01');
```