# How to select rows by date in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have to select all rows from database by just passing date. For example to get all rows that have date `10/23/2012`

In **sqlite db** I store this in `DATE` column:

```
01/01/1900 11:00:00 AM
```

I have tried to get by using `date()` but I get nothing for date:

```
select itemId, date(dateColumn) from items
```

So all I need is to compare only dates but can't find how to do this in sqlite.

Comment: Use a `WHERE`-clause to select only dates matching X

Comment: I tried. But dates have time part also. And I need to get only rows by date. In where clause I need something to get and compare only dates from whole date/time. I have tried with date() function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, format your dates to the ISO-8601 standard.  Wrap it in Date() to ensure it gets processed as a DATE.  Finally, construct your range so that it will include everything from 12:00am onwards until just before 12:00am the next day.

```
select itemId, dateColumn
from items
where dateColumn >= date('2012-10-23')
  AND dateColumn <  date('2012-10-23', '+1 day')
```

**SQLite columns are not typed**. However, if you compare the column to a DATE as shown, it is sufficient to coerced the column data into dates (null if not coercible) and the comparison will work properly.

Example on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2223e/1/0):

```
create table items (
  itemid, datecolumn);
insert into items select
  1,'abc' union all select
  2,null union all select
  3,'10/23/2012 12:23' union all select
  4,'10/23/2012' union all select
  5,'2012-10-23 12:23' union all select
  6,'2012-10-23' union all select
  7,'2012-10-24 12:23' union all select
  8,'2012-10-24' union all select
  9,date('2012-10-24 12:23') union all select
  10,date('2012-10-24');
```

Results:

```
itemid  datecolumn
5       2012-10-23 12:23
6       2012-10-23
```

Note that although rows 3 and 4 ***appear*** to be dates, they are not, because they do not conform to ISO-8601 formatting which is the only format recognized by SQLite.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write it as `WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN date('2012-10-23') AND date('2012-10-23', '+1 day')` ?

Comment: It would not be because that will include the 00:00:00 time of 2012-10-24. The `>=` and `<` pattern is specifically designed to end just before the stroke of midnight of the next day.

Answer (score 5):

In SQLite, there is no datatype `DATE`, it's stored as strings. Therefor, the Strings have to match *exactly* to be equal.

Since we don't want that, you'll want to "cast" the values from the date-column to pseudo-date and also cast your argument to a pseudo-date, so they can be compared:

```
SELECT itemId FROM items WHERE date(dateColumn) = date("2012-10-22");
```

Note that the date-command takes dates formated as `YYYY-MM-DD`, as further explained in an answer to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466688/717341). The question also shows that you can use the `BETWEEN x AND y`-command to get dates, matching a range.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT itemId,dateColumn FROM items WHERE dateColumn=date('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
```

[SQLite Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I can pass only this YYYY-MM-DD (date part).

Answer (score 0):

select itemId,dateColumn from items
where dateColumn = @date