# unable to fetch data in android using cursor

Tags: android

We want to fetch data using cursor which is stored in our table events and fields of table are date, start time and end time.
We want that start time from table where current date=date and current time=start time but we are unable to fetch data.

our database fetch method is as follows......

```
      public String fetch1(String da,String ti)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db =this.getReadableDatabase();

             Cursor c2=db.query(TABLE_eve,new String[]{ KEY_from},KEY_fr_date + "=? AND "+KEY_from + "=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(da),String.valueOf(ti)},null,null,null,null);

             if(c2!=null)

                s= c2.getString(0);
             c2.close();                 
                 db.close();
             return s;
        }
```

and we are calling fetch method in our activity and code is as follows

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                                String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
                                Toast_msg="Exxxx"+datetime;
                        Show_Toast(Toast_msg);


                        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                        String cTime=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                        Toast_msg="Exxxx"+cTime;
                    Show_Toast(Toast_msg);

                //********** code for fetching data from database*****************//

                    t1= dh.fetch1(datetime,cTime);

                    try
                    {
                         String splitTime[]=t1.split(":");
                                         String hours=splitTime[0];
                                 String minutes=splitTime[1];
                                 hr=Integer.parseInt(hours);
                             min=Integer.parseInt(minutes);

                     }
                    catch(Exception e)
                                             {
                         Toast_msg="Exn";
                         Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
                     }
```

Our code is throwing a null pointer exception and the logcat file is

```
04-18 09:19:50.760: D/AndroidRuntime(1122): Shutting down VM
04-18 09:19:50.760: W/dalvikvm(1122): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a1eb90)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): Process: com.event.android, PID: 1122
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.event.android.AddPg$9.onClick(AddPg.java:243)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-18 09:19:50.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 09:19:53.670: I/Process(1122): Sending signal. PID: 1122 SIG: 9
04-18 09:19:55.670: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-18 09:19:55.720: D/gralloc_goldfish(1161): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Please suggest us what to do for fetching data and you may suggest your own code .we have worked a lot on this code but we are not able to fetch

Comment: can you please put all your activity that call fetch method ?? 
is there any try-catch bloc in your code ??

Comment: yes there is a try catch .we have already pasted it in above code

Comment: ca you post all activity that call fetch method ??

Comment: ok . Wait a minute we are posting

Answer (score 0):

This does depend on what type of data the columns store, if you stored it as date time types, then it will need to perform the queries with the correct formats, you can see more on this post: [SQLite, making a query based on Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453300/sqlite-making-a-query-based-on-dates)

Comment: we have stored date and time as TEXT type in our create table query

Comment: please help us...we worked a lot on this code but find no result please please help us...we ,people are getting demoralized since stackoverflow is not giving proper output....

Comment: In that case, make sure that the dates and times are stored in the correct format, you can read more about the formats here: [http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: You can then try and use this query: WHERE DATE(MY_DATE_COLUMN)  BETWEEN ? AND ?, replace the ? with properly formatted dates, I can see in the example code you gave the format of the date is incorrect, it should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:SSS